# Questions about product in algebraic topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

recently I am in great puzzle when studying algebraic topology using Hatcher's book. Questions are as follows:

1. How to understand the "cell" intuitionally? I used to understand it as an open disk, but soon I found that it could also have boundaries.
2. Is there any connection between dimension and topology space? For example, should a 0-cell be in 0-dimension and so on?
3. What is the product of two topological space A and B? According to Hatcher, the product of two spaces is actually the product of the cells in A and B, but what is the product of cells? For example, a torus is S1 x S1, and S1 is composed of e0 and e1. So I guess the answer should be a set of e0 x e0, e1 x e1, e1 x e0, e0 x e1. What is e0 x e0 or the other like? For example, e0 is a point, so e0 x e0 should be also a point, and the dimension is higher?

Comment: This is not a question about research level mathematics, and so it is off topic on this website. On a side note, you might want to learn some general topology before studying algebraic topology.

Comment: This question is definitely not suitable for this site...  $e_0\times e_0$ is just like cartesian product of sets..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are refering to CW complex.

> How to understand the "cell" intuitionally? I used to understand it as an open disk, but soon I found that it could also have boundaries.

Well, that depends if we are talking about open cells or closed cells. Open cells are very easy to understand - they are simply open balls (up to homeomorphism).

Closed cells on the other hand can be quite complicated. By the definition a closed cell is the image of a closed ball under an attaching map. So it can be a closed ball itself. But it can be for a example a sphere or any other monstrosity generated by an attachment map.

Note that an open cell is the "inside" of the associated closed cell.

For example in the case of the sphere $S^1\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ in the complex plane. We can introduce the following CW structure: one $0$-cell $\{1\}$ and one closed $1$-cell $S^1$. The attaching map glues ends of $1$-dimensional ball (i.e. the closed interval) with the single $0$-cell. There never are open $0$-cells. There is one open $1$-cell, namely $S^1\backslash\{1\}$. It is the "inside" of $S^1$. Note that the closed cell $S^1$ **is not** homeomorphic to a closed ball.

You can take a different CW structure on $S^1$: two $0$-cells $\{1\}, \{-1\}$ and two closed $1$-cells $\{z\in S^1\ |\ \text{im}(z)\geq 0\}$ and $\{z\in S^1\ |\ \text{im}(z)\leq 0\}$ (here $\text{im}$ denotes the imaginary part so those sets are the upper and the lower halves of the sphere). Now both closed cells **are** homeomorphic to closed balls. Attaching maps glue one end of the closed interval to $\{-1\}$ and the other to $\{1\}$ producing our cells.

> Is there any connection between dimension and topology space? For example, should a 0-cell be in 0-dimension and so on?

Yes, $n$-cell is $n$-dimensional by definition. The dimension of the entire CW complex is defined as the maximum among dimensions of its cells.

> What is the product of two topological space A and B? According to Hatcher, the product of two spaces is actually the product of the cells in A and B, but what is the product of cells?

Product as in [the Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). This is what it is in terms of sets. The topology is then defined as [the product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology). It is "inherited" from both components. Cells are topological spaces so it makes perfect sense to talk about their product.

> For example, e0 is a point, so e0 x e0 should be also a point, and the dimension is higher?

Yes, product of singletons is again a singleton. And no, the dimension does not increase. The formula for dimension is quite simple:

$$\dim(X\times Y)=\dim(X)+\dim(Y)$$

and the dimension of a point (or finite set of points) is $0$.

For example take a plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a line $\mathbb{R}$. They have dimensions $2$ and $1$ respectively. But their product $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^3$ is the $3$-dimensional space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it helped me a lot! I still have two problems. 1. You mentioned that S1 is composed of 0-cell and 1-cell, which is S1. But is 1-cell S1 instead of an interval? I think S1 is actually a circle.

Comment: Also, why must  n-cell be n-dimension? For example, if the e0, which is a point, is (1,2,3), shouldn't it be in the three-dimension? My question is silly and thanks for your patient answer!

Comment: @Sooner Yes, $S^1$ is a circle. The closed 1-cell (my first CW structure of $S^1$) is the whole circle. Remember that closed cells are intervals **after** applying an attaching map - in this case glueing two ends of an interval to obtain the circle.

Comment: @Sooner "n-cell" is just another way of writing "n-dimensional cell". A point $(x,y,z)$ is 0 dimensional, even though taken from 3 dimensional space. Analogously a circle is 1 dimensional even though each point has two coordinates (taken from the 2 dimensional complex plane). The dimension is calculated based on cells, not on containing space.

Comment: For the S1, I have an understanding and if I am wrong, please tell me. The closed 1-cell may be understood as 1-ball, which is an interval. The closed 2-cell is a 2-ball, which is a disk including a circle boundary and the interior. The closed 3-cell is a 3-ball which is a ball which its interior is full. So S1 is a circle, only the circle and it is the boundary of the closed 2-cell, which is a disk, so this is one way to construct S1. Also we could use closed 1-cell, which is an interval and could also be called 1-ball, and a point( 0-cell ), so that we use a attaching map to get the S1 too.

Comment: @Sooner You are confusing things. What you are proposing **is not** how you construct CW complexes. You construct CW complex by starting with a discrete (possibly finite) set of points which are 0 dimensional cells. Then you attach higher dimensional balls to lower dimensional skeleton via attachment map. Whether $S^1$ is a boundary of $D^2$ is **irrelevant**. That's not how you construct CW complexes. Forget about boundary notion. It is irrelevant to the construction.

Comment: And again: closed cell **is not** a ball. Closed cell is the image of a ball under the attachment map. The example is given by $S^1$ constructed from a 0 dimensional cell (a point) and 1-dimensional cell as **the image** of closed interval via attachment map that glues both ends. Perhaps you should read again Hatcher from the scratch. :)

Comment: Thank you again, and I guess I must be a trouble-maker who learned slowly. According to Hatcher's instruction, if we want to construct $X^n$, then we need to add $D^n$ to $X^{n-1}$. But how to add it? So we need an attachment map $\varphi$, which maps the boundary of $D^n$, which is $\delta$D, to the $X^{n-1}$. For example if you want to get $S^1$, you need 0-cell as $X^{n-1}$ and 1-cell, which an interval. So you map the interval's boundary, which is the two end points to the $X^{n-1}$ so we get the $S^1$.

Comment: That is what I understand according to Hatcher's instruction, but I did not see anything about open cell or closed cell. So I am confused about what you say, and I am sorry for my bad understanding.

Comment: @Sooner Ok, so I've read Hatcher's book directly. For Hatcher $n$-cell is what I called an open $n$-cell (see: Standard Notations at the begining of the book). At least at the begining, I'm not sure if he follows the convention throughout the book. The notation is confusing and whenever you talk/read about cells you have to make sure whether people are talking about closed or open cells.

Comment: For Hatcher attaching an **open** $n$-cell actually means making a disjoint union $X^{n-1}\sqcup D^n$ and make a quotient space via relation $x\sim f(x)$ for $x\in\partial D^n$ and $f:\partial D^n\to X^{n-1}$ the attaching map. It sort of makes sense, because actually only points from the open ball are added to the structure. The boundary is glued to the existing skeleton. But I still find it confusing.

Comment: So I guess in a sense we were both right. :)

Comment: Woo you are so so so so kind to me! I always think that I may be a bad learner because I am so confused. When I read smash product or join operation I think "Oh my gosh! I must be a silly man. This is just a start and I can not even understand it!" I think you give me much confidence( If what I said is true under your approval). So actually I think this subject, or the general topology needs more intuition first. Thank you so much and I am very lucky to be taught by you. You are such a good teacher!